# -debug flag for converter

Tags: debugging, netbeans, javacard

I'm using NetBeans with JavaCard plugin installed to write and test my applets. The problem is that I need to have a debug component to be included into the resulting .cap file. I know that there is a converter option -debug, which does exactly what I need, but I cant figure out how to pass this option to building process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I have found a solution. I didn't find an elegant solution though.

Netbeans uses jc-pack Ant task to convert files into .cap. This task is defined in Packager class which is included into src folder of the jcdk installation folder.

The convertation process is in Packager.java line ~205.
I have modified Packager.java to add -debug flag for the converter.

After that I've built tools.jar out of these modified sources.

And finally I've replaced tools.jar in simulator/lib folder.

Please let me know if you find a better solution.